# ASP Button not displaying on Windows 2012 Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've an application that display information in a gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="X-Small" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
PageSize="100" DataSourceID="SiteDataSource1" Width="100%">
<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="20" Position="TopAndBottom" />
<RowStyle CssClass="itemstyle" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altstyle" />    
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Description">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Identifier" HeaderText="Identifier" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Identifier">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="State">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="HostHeaderValue" HeaderText="Host Header Value" ReadOnly="True"
        SortExpression="HostHeaderValue" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IP Address" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IPAddress" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Port" HeaderText="Port" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Port" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SSLPort" HeaderText="SSL Port" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SSLPort" />
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Control"
                OnClick="Button_Clicked" Text="Control" Width="50" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

the status of the button is set

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataRowView entry = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    switch (entry["State"] as string)
                    {
                        case "Stopped":
                            e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
                            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                            ((Button)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[1]).Text = "Start";
                            ((Button)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[1]).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            ((Button)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[1]).CommandArgument = entry["Site"] as string + "|" + entry["Description"] as string;
                            break;
                        case "Running":
                            e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Honeydew;
                            ((Button)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[1]).Text = "Stop";
                            ((Button)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[1]).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            ((Button)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[1]).CommandArgument = entry["Site"] as string + "|" + entry["Description"] as string;
                            break;
                        default:
                            e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                            e.Row.Cells[7].Text = "";
                            break;

                    }
```

on a Windows 2008 server the button displays with no issues, however when I view this page with the gridview the column with the button is empty on a Windows 2012 server. Has anyone seen this before? Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: turns out there was a database query that runs to validate the server is in an admin group after the button is set, atm the query is returning null so this is why the button is being disabled. Thanks for all the advice/help

Answer (score 0):

turns out there was a database query that runs to validate the server is in an admin group after the button is set, atm the query is returning null so this is why the button is being disabled. Thanks for all the advice/help